# What is a good strategy to beat Funtime Foxy's Darkroom

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-help-wanted

So I finally got past Plushbaby's level but now I'm completely stuck on Funtime Foxy's level. Whenever I get to the exit Foxy is always standing right in front of it and he kills me no matter which direction I go.

I tried looking up a way to get past the level but every strategy I found seemed to contradict the last. I found one that said to go straight at Foxy and then just go off to the left of him at the exit and I found another that said to move alternating left to right in between flashes. Neither worked and Foxy just killed me when I got close to the exit.

What's a good strategy to get past Funtime Foxy's Dark Room?